# Testing anonymous functions

Tags: go

I'm trying to understand the best way to test this module in Go.

This is the module,

```
package datasource

import "time"

type DataSource interface {
    Value(key string) (interface{}, error)
}
```

This is tied into two other modules in the package, database and cache, which respectively have functions for showing values and storing them.

The implementation I'm looking to do for testing is, with a test module,

package datasource

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func createRandomData(t *testing.T) {
    //arg creates new argument
    arr := [3]string{"apple", "banana", "apricot"}
    fmt.Println(arr)

    Value(arr)
    fmt.Println(testing work?)
}
```

I want to be able to send test data through the function simply - trying to find the best pathway to do this.

I am stuck on making this data go through the anonymous function in the top module - I think by passing the array into Value, it should test it no?

Error on using sample code,

```
# datasource [datasource.test]
/home/incompleteness_hewlbern/Documents/Code_Projects/Tests/nearmap/Private_test_golang/datasource/datasource_test.go:38:3: cannot use arr (type map[string]string) as type map[string]interface {} in field value
note: module requires Go 1.15
FAIL    datasource [build failed]
FAIL
```

Thanks for the help!

Using this,

```
package datasource

import (
    "fmt"
)

type DataSource interface {
    Value(key string) (interface{}, error)
}

// MyNewDs type, implements the DataSource interface
type MyNewDS struct {
    data map[string]string
}

func (n *MyNewDS) Value(key string) (interface{}, error) {
    if _, ok := n.data[key]; ok {
        return n.data[key], nil
    } else {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("key not found %v", ok)
    }
}

func getFromDS(datasource DataSource, key string) (string, error) {
    v, err := datasource.Value(key)
    if err != nil {
        return "", nil
    }

    return fmt.Sprint(v), nil
}
```

and the below test script.

Comment: *"I think by passing the array into Value, it should test it no?"* -- No. You've got a number of different errors there, all of them very basic, betraying your lack of knowledge of Go fundamentals. I would suggest you take the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1).

Comment: Thanks - The Go tour, i feel like it isn't very in depth and misses out on some of the key concepts required to do things like the above, but will go back through it

Comment: Where is the anonymous function?!

Comment: A few comments: 1. That's not a module. It's a package (note the keyword 'package' at the top). 2. "modules in a package" is nonsense. Perhaps you mean "packages in a module"? 3. There are no anonymous functions in your code, so your title doesn't make much sense. 4. You mention a "test script" -- There's no such thing as a Go script. Go is compiled. Scripts, by definition, are interpreted.

Comment: Gah Golang community is not the same as javascript haha fml, sorry i'm just trying to learn - very newbie, this has helped a lot with learning so far though

Answer (score 1):

The original edit of the question was a little closer to making sense. Here's answer based on that version.

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "time"
)

type Database struct {
    data map[string]interface{}
}

func (db *Database) Value(key string) (interface{}, error) {
    // simulate 500ms roundtrip to the distributed cache
    time.Sleep(100500 * time.Millisecond)
    return db.data[key], nil
}

func TestDatabase(t *testing.T) {
    db := &Database{data: map[string]interface{}{
        "orange": "bad",
        "jack":   "good",
    }}

    if v, err := db.Value("jack"); err != nil || v != "good" {
        t.Errorf("Value(jack) = %s, want good", v)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Interface types can be confusing to start with, don't think of them as a type think of them as behavior.

In the case of your `DataSource` interface type, what you're saying is any type that implements a Value method satisfies the `DataSource` behavior.

So this could be (long winded example):

**datasource.go**

```
package datasource

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type DataSource interface {
    Value(key string) (interface{}, error)
}

// MyNewDs type, implements the DataSource interface
type MyNewDS struct {
    data map[string]string
}

func (n *MyNewDS) Value(key string) (interface{}, error) {
    if _, ok := n.data[key]; ok {
        return n.data[key], nil
    } else {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("key not found %v", ok)
    }
}

// Database type, implements the DataSource interface
type Database struct {
    data map[string]string
}

func (db *Database) Value(key string) (interface{}, error) {
    // simulate 500ms roundtrip to the distributed cache
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)

    return db.data[key], nil
}

func getFromDS(datasource DataSource, key string) (string, error) {
    v, err := datasource.Value(key)
    if err != nil {
        return "", nil
    }

    return fmt.Sprint(v), nil
}
```

**datasource_test.go**

```
package datasource

import (
    "testing"
)

// TestDataSource test that an
func TestMyNewDS(t *testing.T) {
    arr := map[string]string{
        "apple": "yes",
        "banana": "yes",
        "apricot": "yes",
    }
    ds := MyNewDS{
        data: arr,
    }

    for k, v := range ds.data {
        res, err := ds.Value(k)
        if err != nil {
            t.Errorf("%T does not implement Value method correctly, key %v not found", ds, k)
        }
        if res != v {
            t.Errorf("%T does not implement Value correctly. Expected %v but recieved %v: %v", ds, v, res, err)
        }

    }
}

// TestDataSource test that an
func TestDatabase(t *testing.T) {
    arr := map[string]string{
        "apple": "yes",
        "banana": "yes",
        "apricot": "yes",
    }
    ds := Database{
        data: arr,
    }

    for k, v := range ds.data {
        res, err := ds.Value(k)
        if err != nil {
            t.Errorf("%T does not implement Value method correctly, key %v not found", ds, k)
        }
        if res != v {
            t.Errorf("%T does not implement Value correctly. Expected %v but recieved %v: %v", ds, v, res, err)
        }

    }

}
```

Both the MyNewDS and Database types implement the DataSource interface. When testing though you would have to write a unit test for each of the types.

Additionally, you would only really want to do something like this if you were trying to create some kind of generic function (getFromDS) that could accept either type.